# Copy local file to another location with a web page

Tags: javascript, browser, copy, html

I do not know if this is possible to do.

What I want to achieve is a web page (online) where once you select an image from my pc via a classical input in html, let me copy it to another folder always inside of my PC (or a PC connected to the network local).

I can do this thing? Maybe with javascript?

There are other possible solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: websites are not permitted access to your local filesystem. Allowing this would be a MASSIVE security risk. There is pretty much literally nothing you can do to make this work, short of completely torpedoing any kind of security your system may have had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Websites have no permission to access Your computer local system. With HTML `<input type="file">` You can only send files to the chosen website directory. Eventually, You can download those files later and put them on the other place in Your system.

Comment: So I have no possible solution?

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti Unfortunately, no. This is impossible cuz of the security resons.